# C++: Redefinition of template class with different types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, enums, template-specialization

I have two(multiple) enums:

```
enum Choices1 : int
{
    a,
    b
};
enum Choices2 : int
{
    c,
    d
};
```

I want to be able to associate a Type to each of these enum choices. If I only had one set of enums say `Choices1`, I could introduce:

```
template <Choices1 c>
struct choice_traits;
```

and then specialise it for each entry:

```
template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices1::a> 
{
    using MyType = float;
};

template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices1::b> 
{
    using MyType = double;
```

But I want to be able to do it for multiple enums, while using the same keyword, ie something like:

```
template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices1::a>
{...};

template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices1::b>
{...};

template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices2::c>
{...};

template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices2::d>
{...};
```

Is this possible? if so, what would be the non specialised case?

**If not, is there any alternative way of associating a Type to each of `(Choice1::a,Choice1::b,Choice2::c,Choice2::d)` and potentially more such enums?**

Comment: I think c++1z auto template parameter could do the trick here. [Example](https://godbolt.org/g/ZDHTiR)

Comment: interesting! Anything else until then?

Comment: I'm afraid before c++1z you need to pass the type of the enum apart from value...

Comment: yeah I am trying to avoid that. :/

Comment: Yes I got that from your question... I don't like macros but maybe [this](https://godbolt.org/g/uKrKQy) could be the answer for you

Comment: Nah, guess I will wait till C++17 arrives. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a great solution but... you can use the common base (`int`) for `Choiches1` and `Choiches2` and define the not specialized case as

```
template <int>
struct choice_traits;
```

At this point the problem is that `Choiches1::a == Coiches2::c` and `Choiches1::b == Choiches2::d` so, if you want define something like

```
template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices1::a> 
 { using MyType = float; };

template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices1::b> 
 { using MyType = double; };

template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices2::c> 
 { using MyType = int; };

template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices2::d> 
 { using MyType = long; };
```

yuo have to avoid collisions between `Choiches1` and `Choiches2` values.

If you know the number of `Choiches1` values, you can start `Choiches2` with a bigger number; by example, if you're sure that there are minus than 100 `Choiches1` values, you can define the enums as follows

```
enum Choices1 : int
{ a = 0, b };

enum Choices2 : int
{ c = 100, d };
```

Another solution can be use even and odd values for the two enums; something like

```
enum Choices1 : int
{ a = 0, b = a+2 }; // add 2 for every next value

enum Choices2 : int
{ c = 1, d = c+2 }; // add 2 for every next value
```

The following is a full example

```
enum Choices1 : int
{ a = 0, b };

enum Choices2 : int
{ c = 100, d };

template <int>
struct choice_traits;

template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices1::a> 
 { using MyType = float; };

template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices1::b> 
 { using MyType = double; };

template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices2::c> 
 { using MyType = int; };

template <>
struct choice_traits<Choices2::d> 
 { using MyType = long; };

int main()
 {
   choice_traits<a>::MyType fl { 1.1f };
   choice_traits<b>::MyType db { 2.2 };
   choice_traits<c>::MyType in { 3 };
   choice_traits<d>::MyType ln { 4L };
 }
```

Comment: Nice hackery. Unfortunately this means that the providers of these enums have to take the responsibility of managing their values for the use of the choice_traits framework that I am building on top, which is too much to ask I think.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some excessive solution:

```
template <class Enum, Enum e>
struct choice_traits;

template<>
struct choice_traits<Choices1, Choices1::b>
{
      typedef float MyType;
};

//using
typename choice_traits<Choices1, Choices1::b>::MyType m {0.0};
```